# Trigger Google Workflow from document update in Firestore

Tags: google-workflows

When there is an update in my Cloud Firestore, I would like it to trigger a workflows that consumes the document id as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage EventArc to have an event reported to Audit Logs be picked up by EventArc and used as trigger for your Workflow.

Essentially the command is from this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/workflows/create-triggers#cloud-audit-logs-events_1) page:

```
gcloud eventarc triggers create TRIGGER \
    --location=LOCATION \
    --destination-workflow=DESTINATION_WORKFLOW \
    --destination-workflow-location=DESTINATION_WORKFLOW_LOCATION \
    --event-filters="type=google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written" \
    --event-filters="serviceName=SERVICE_NAME" \
    --event-filters="methodName=METHOD_NAME" \
    --service-account="MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

where the event-filter

- serviceName= firestore.googleapis.com
- methodName=pick from a list

the methodName options are described [on this page](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/reference/supported-events#cloud-firestore).